# Are there any adjectives ending in -фый/-фий/-фой?

Tags: прилагательные

Are there any Russian adjectives, whether they end in -ый, -ий, or -ой, whose final consonant is ф? (I.e. -фый, -фий, -фой)

Comment: Нет. http://loopy.ru/?word=***%D1%84%D0%B8%D0%B9&def= http://loopy.ru/?word=****%D1%84%D0%B8%D0%B9&def=

Answer (score 6):

I would probably go with "[жирафий](http://gramota.ru/slovari/dic/?word=%E6%E8%F0%E0%F4%E8%E9&all=x)". Not so sure about the ones ending with "-фый" or "-фой".

Answer (score 0):

No there are not, the set of word ending by `-ф` (or with `ф`+vowel) is actually small and constitutes only from foreign words - originally there was no `f` sound in Slavic languages at all. As a rule mostly all of them end with `-овый`, like in "шельфовый", "трефовый", "кайфовый", ["графовый"](https://ru.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%84%D0%BE%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%B9) (for mathematical concept), "блефовый", "лафовый" (from "лафа") etc.

As or "жираф" that already've been mentioned (I've upvoted that answer) there are two adjectives derived, "жирафовый" and, indeed ["жирафий"](https://ru.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D0%B6%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%84%D0%B8%D0%B9), however from my (understandably very limited) experience of hearing this word is quite often pronounced as "жирафьий" - it's influenced by the the rest of the grammatical cases where `-ь` occurs.

Actually the reason for this is that that while the `-овый` morpheme is productive in Russian, the "-oй" (without the "oв" part)so I hardly believe that words ending with `ф` are something special here.

Answer (score -1):

-фой — no.

-фий — theoretically, a possessive one such as *графий* ("the count’s").

-фый — theoretically again, and definitely crossing into occasionalisms, something of the [adjective]-[noun]ed type (as in "dark-haired") where the noun would end in -ф or -фа. I can't think of anything less whimsical and unlikely than *многошкафая комната* ("many-closeted room") or *длиннострофые стихи* ("long-stanzaed verse").

**UPDATE:** Before anyone else flames me about *многошкафая комната*, a recap:

- We shouldn't even be discussing the merits of the word. It's correctly formed; it *could* exist; that answers the question.
- But if we're discussing it anyway: *многошкафая комната* is a witticism; *многошкафная комната* is a solecism. There exists a combination of meaning and intended effect (facetious, perhaps referencing the Futurists) for which *многошкафая* would be the best fit. Good luck finding a use for *многошкафная* or *многошкафовая* that doesn't end up being just a really awkward way to say *комната со множеством шкафов* or *комната, где много шкафов*.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/92687/discussion-on-answer-by-nikolay-ershov-are-there-any-adjectives-ending-in-).